# Ошибка при выполнении gitsync

Tags: git

При выполнении команды gitsync возникает ошибка: **Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.** Была старая версия Git 2.21.0, обновление не помогло. Подскажите, как исправить данную проблему?
Версия Git 2.31.1

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: всегда под админом работаешь или только для обновления переключился?

Comment: @Эникейщик, работаю всегда под админом

Comment: тогда нет версий